Does $e^{At}$ converges to projection operator in Banach space?
Let $A:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear Banach space operator. In their book, Daleckii and Krein show that if the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is real and strictly negative, then the operator $P: X \rightarrow X$ defined by $Px = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{At}x$ is the zero map. The do this by showing that
$$|||x||| = \int_0^\infty ||e^{At}x|| \: dt$$
defines a norm topologically equivalent to the original norm on the Banach space. The result easily follows.
I am interested in what happens when we allow $0$ to be in the spectrum. If $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then the result clearly does not hold. For example, any non-zero $x \in \ker(A)$ will satisfy $e^{At}x = x$ for all $t \geq 0$.
But what if we suppose that $0$ is in the continuous or residual spectrum of $A$? Put simply, I’m interested in the following question:
Question: Let $A:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear Banach space operator with non-positive real spectrum $\sigma(A)$. Suppose $0 \in \sigma(A)$, but it is not an eigenvalue. Does $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{At}x = 0$ for all $x\in A$?
As soft affirmative evidence, this does seem to be case if $X$ is a separable Hilbert space and $A$ is self-adjoint. In particular, we can use the spectral theorem to obtain this result. Is there some analogue to self-adjoint that we would need to make this work in an arbitrary Banach space?

Example ${\bf 1}$
Let $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and
$$A(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n,\ldots )=(0,-{x_1\over 2},-{x_2\over 3},\ldots, -{x_n\over n+1},\ldots )$$ Then $A$ is a compact operator with no eigenvalues. Thus $\sigma(A)=\{0\}.$ Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ denote the standard basis in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}).$ Then $Ae_k={1\over k+1}e_{k+1}.$ Hence $A^ke_1= {(-1)^k\over (k+1)!}e_{k+1}$ and  $$e^{tA}e_1=\left (I+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {t^k\over k!}A^k\right )e_1=e_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-t)^k\over k!(k+1)!}e_{k+1}$$ Therefore $\|e^{tA}e_1\|\ge 1.$ Moreover the limit of $e^{tA}e_1$ when $t\to\infty$ does not exists since $\langle e^{tA}e_1,e_2\rangle ={-t\over 2}.$
Example $\bf 2$
What follows  resembles Example $ 1$ except that operator $A$ is diagonal.
Let $X=c$ be the Banach space of all convergent sequences. Consider $(Ax)_n=-n^{-1}x_n.$ Then $\sigma(A)=\{0\}\cup\{-n^{-1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $0$ is not an eigenvalue. We have $$(e^{tA}x)_n=e^{-n^{-1}t}x_n$$ Thus $$\|e^{tA}x\|=\sup_n e^{-n^{-1}t}|x_n|$$ For ${\bf 1}=(1,1,\ldots)$ we get $\|e^{tA}{\bf 1}\|=1.$ Hence $e^{tA}\bf 1$ does not tend to $0,$ when $t\to\infty.$ Actually $e^{tA}\bf 1$ is not convergent as it is convergent  to $0$ pointwise but the norms do not tend to $0.$
Let $c_0$ denote the subspace of all sequences convergent to $0.$ This subspace has codimension  $1.$ For $x\in c_0$ we have $e^{tA}x\to 0,$ when $t\to \infty.$

Wonderful example! Do you have any ideas on some kind of condition I could add on $X$ to make this true? For example, it certainly works on $\ell^p$ for all $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Also this might be a silly question, but what is the limit in this example?

Concerning your second question I have extended the answer showing that the limit does not exist. Concerning your first question I do not know what assumptions  for the space $X$ could be added

@Joe The closest thing to a Hilbert space in Banach space land are reflexive spaces and self dual spaces. Perhaps there's something there along these lines.
